# MongoDB query for string variations of zero?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, zero

If I want to query for a field that equals zero as in:

```
BasicDBObject queryForZero = new BasicDBObject("field", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "0"));
```

But I want to be able to also retrieve objects whose "field" value is zero but not written as "0" - i.e.: "0.0", and "0.00", and "0.000" etc..

Is there a way to query for zeros that compares the numeric value?

Comment: @JohnnyHK the field itself is a String - I tried that, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I think you'd want to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `$regex` regular expression match for non-trivial string matching. For the 0 patterns listed, you could use:

```
new BasicDBObject("field", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^0(\.0+)?$"));
```

Click [here](https://regexper.com/#%5E0(%5C.0%2B)%3F%24) for an explanation of the regular expression used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnnyHK said, try using a regex:

```
BasicDBObject queryForZero = new BasicDBObject("field", "/0+\.*0*/");
```

Comment: I tried: BasicDBObject queryForZero = new BasicDBObject("field", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "0+.*0*"));  It matches with anything that has a zero in it - like "100" or "2.50" instead of just zero.